# iOS Use UIWebView to execute JavaScript string using Math.pow

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, eval

I want to evaluate a string which is written in JavaScipt in iOS and learned I can to that by using: 
`[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:formula]`

The code I'm using is:

`NSString *formula = @"( 1.5 * Math.pow(2, 3) ) / 12";
formula = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"eval('%@')", formula];
NSInteger value = [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:formula] integerValue];`

The problem is the Math.pow function. If I dont use it , I get a real value form the webView. If I have Math.pow in the string, I just get empty string back.
Can anyone help me how to change the code so I can use strings which contains Math.pow?

Comment: did you try to wrap that into javascript method and execute f.e [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:myMethod();"] in your js method execute needed calculations and print output number

Comment: why do you need that -> you can execute such calculations natively

Comment: Im not too good with JS so how would that code look like?

Comment: I get the string from a server which only can send JS :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
NSInteger value = [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:formula] integerValue];
```

where you are converting your result in a integer value. So, it gets rounded off.

Correct would be:

```
float value = [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:formula] floatValue];
```

notice both the `value` type and the use of `floatValue` for the conversion from string.

BTW, you do not need the eval, strictly.

Comment: This has no effect on the JS result which is an empty string @"".

Comment: In my case it is working, I tested it before posting. If I use 24 instead of 12, I get 0.5